# Java list contains - produces false positives because of duplicate hash codes

Tags: java, hash

This is probably very basic,
I have a list of "Cards" where a Card object only has a "number" field (int).
Another list "listB" contains a subset of that list.

As I loop through the first list, and examine each element if it:

```
listB.contains(card);
```

I get false positives. Some cards that have the same number but are not a part of listB return "true". The reason must be that they have the same hash code.

How do I avoid this collision without uglifying the simple "Card" class?
I just want each Card instance to be unique, regardless of it "number" value

```
public interface Card {
}

public class NumberCard implements Card {
private int number;

public NumberCard(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return Integer.toString(number);
}
}

public class Setup {
public static List<Card> getCards(){
    List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
    int amount = 4;
    add(cards, 4, new NumberCard(0));
    add(cards, 4, new NumberCard(1));
    add(cards, 4, new NumberCard(2));
    add(cards, 4, new NumberCard(3));
    add(cards, 4, new NumberCard(4));

    return cards;
}

private static void add(List<Card> cards, int amount, Card card) {
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        cards.add(card);
    }
}
}
public DeckOfCards() {
    cards = Setup.getCards();
    Collections.shuffle(cards);
}
public class Player {
private List<Card> cards;
private List<Card> hidden;
```

}

If I store random 4 Cards in a "Player" "cards" field
And then select 2 out of 4 as "hidden"
If the same card number appears in both "hidden" an non "hidden" then

for(Card card : cards) { if(hidden.contains(card) {

will return true for both hidden" an non "hidden"

Comment: Could you provide the implementation of the `Card` class? `contains` checks for equality using the `equals` method.

Comment: Provide an example of a false-positive case,

Comment: Provide your code, did you override the `hascode/equals`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things in order to deal with this situation:

1. Create another field, say `private String id` in `NumberCard` and make sure that the value of this field is unique for each card. In other words, this field should serve as a unique identifier for each card.
2. Override `hashCode()` and `equals()` in `NumberCard` e.g. as follows:

   ```
   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       return Objects.hash(number, id);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       NumberCard other = (NumberCard) obj;
       return this.number == other.number && this.id.equals(other.id);
   }
   ```

Comment: I will try. thanks. I was hoping for something more out of the box from the language perspective that will not require me to implement random unique numbers. something like comparing memory addresses to determine it these objects are the same. (like in c#)